# How to simulate a cache and memory with C code?

Tags: c, unit-testing, hardware

I have a work that need to design unit test for functions.

One of the function (or MACRO) will do the cache flush or cache invalidate.

But the point is, this target code runs on the different hardware with the test program does.

So, the function of cache operation cannot be tested directly because of the different hardware and maybe there will produce some error to run it.

Therefore, I need to simulate the cache operation like flush and invalidate by `C` code to test the other function which may use these operations.

I know the number of cache line and how do I simulate it by C code?

Comment: What are you trying to test, and why do you care about the CPU caches during a unit test?  Is what you're actually implementing a performance benchmark, rather than a unit test?

Comment: In general you can simulate or model any type of digital system in C because it is a general purpose programming language.  Could you be more specific about what you need?  What input would your program take and what output would it give and what platform does it run on?  Can you give some examples?  If I'm going to spend time writing an answer for you, how do I know what the criteria are for you to accept it?  This is very broad so far.

Comment: There are many different kinds of cache that might be in play at any given time. Your CPU cache is one of them, and the one your function or macro needs to flush may or may not be a totally different one, the latter is much more probable. If, against all odds, your function *does* flush and/or invalidate the CPU cache, then I'm afraid unit testing it will be very difficult. You will need tools to examine the state of the cache, which normal programs cannot easily do. Simulating the CPU cache does not make much sense, as the cache is functionally invisible.